# How to update the Z value using an UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I'm trying to update the Z value using UpdateCursor, the problem is the update is not working.

```py
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict
import random
from statistics import StatisticsError, mode

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Samaali\PycharmProjects\ProjetApplication\venv\data"

original_shapefile = "test.shp"
backup_shapefile = "testCopy.shp"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(original_shapefile, backup_shapefile)

#Dictionary to store points with the same x, y values
points_by_coordinate = defaultdict(list)

#Set to keep track of processed polyline pairs, to avoid repetition in the result
processed_pairs = set()

#Create a search cursor to iterate through each feature of the shapefile
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(original_shapefile, ["SHAPE@", "ID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        geometry = row[0]
        feature_id = row[1]
        for part in geometry:
            for p in part:
                point = (p.X, p.Y, p.Z, feature_id)
                points_by_coordinate[(point[0], point[1])].append(point)

#Keep only the values with more than one point in the list
points_by_coordinate = {key: value for key, value in points_by_coordinate.items() if len(value) > 1}

#Calculate the most frequent z value for each key
most_frequent_z = {}
for key, value in points_by_coordinate.items():
    z_values = [point[2] for point in value]
    try:
        # Try to find a unique mode
        most_frequent_z[key] = mode(z_values)
    except StatisticsError:
        # If there is no unique mode, choose randomly from the equally common values
        most_frequent_z[key] = random.choice([max(set(z_values), key=z_values.count)])

#Create a dictionary to store Z values for each feature ID
feature_z_values = defaultdict(dict) 

#Start an editing session
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()

#Iterate through the features and update Z values
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(backup_shapefile, ["SHAPE@", "ID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        geometry = row[0]
        feature_id = row[1]
        new_parts = []
        for part in geometry:
            new_points = []
            for p in part:
                key = (p.X, p.Y)
                if key in most_frequent_z:
                    # Update the Z value with the chosen most frequent value
                    new_points.append(arcpy.Point(p.X, p.Y, most_frequent_z[key]))
                    # Store the Z value for the current feature ID and key
                    feature_z_values[feature_id][key] = most_frequent_z[key]
                else:
                    # Keep the original point
                    new_points.append(p)
            new_parts.append(new_points)

        # Create a new Polyline geometry with the updated parts
        new_geometry = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(new_parts), True)

        # Update the row with the new geometry
        row[0] = new_geometry
        cursor.updateRow(row)

#Print the feature ID and corresponding Z values
for feature_id, z_values_dict in feature_z_values.items():
    print("Feature ID: {0}, Z Values: {1}".format(feature_id, z_values_dict))

#Stop the editing session
edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

Comment: I would put in a print statement to display whats in `new_geometry` as that is what is feeding into the update cursor, verify it contains _what you think it should have_ then work backwards.

Comment: When using ArcPy Geometry constructors, it is best practice to include a spatial reference.  Also, the current code will take a multi-part polyline and only return the last part, which doesn't seem like an intentional outcome.

Comment: It's not only *best* practice to specify the correct `SpatialReference` in the `Geometry` constructor, it's the ***only*** practice that won't collapse vertex precision of decimal degree data. But, @Hornbydd, the code block is correct for multi-part handling. I'm not convinced the Z value lookup is correct, though.